# For loop runs and perform task on only the first element of the the iterable but not the rest and returns the result of only the action on 1st element

Tags: python

The last for loop of the code seems to only run for the first element of the list and not the rest of the element

```
a = int(input())
setA = set(map(int, input().split()))
n = int(input())
com = [input() for alnum in range(n*2)]
nestcom = []
cmd = []
for i in com:
    if com.index(i)%2 == 0:
        nestcom.append([i, com[com.index(i)+1]])
    else:
        continue
for x in nestcom:
    y, z = x[0].split(), set(map(int, x[1].split()))
    cmd.append([y, z])
for u in cmd:
    eval('setA.'+cmd[0][0][0]+'('+str(cmd[0][1])+')')
print(sum(setA))
```

These are the inputs
16
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 24 52
4
intersection_update 10
2 3 5 6 8 9 1 4 7 11
update 2
55 66
symmetric_difference_update 5
22 7 35 62 58
difference_update 7
11 22 35 55 58 62 66

I tried running code with python 3 and pypy 3 but same problem. I changed the eval() to exec() but problem still persist

Comment: Please provide example inputs that illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is your last loop:

```py
for u in cmd:
    eval('setA.'+cmd[0][0][0]+'('+str(cmd[0][1])+')')
```

You are using `cmd` in what you are doing within the loop, not `u`. That is, you aren't using each element in `cmd`, you are just using `cmd` a number of times.

You likely want to use `u` in the loop itself (like `eval('setA.'+u[0]...)`), or perhaps `enumerate(cmd)` to get each element and a counter and use the counter itself, like `for i, u in enumerate(cmd): eval('setA.'+cmd[i][0][0]...)`

Comment: Thank you very much. That was stupid of me to do that. Your comment was really helpful

Comment: glad to help. if you mark the post as accepted / upvote it, it will let others know as well that the question is solved